# Replace a block of text

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I have a file in this pattern:

```
Some text
---

## [Unreleased]
More text here
```

I need to replace the text between '---' and '## [Unreleased]' with something else in a shell script.
How can it be achieved using sed or awk?

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lne 'my @replacement = ("First line", "Second line");
           if ($p = (/^---$/ .. /^## \[Unreleased\]/)) {
               print $replacement[$p-1];
           } else { print }'
```

The flip-flop operator `..` tells you whether you're between the two strings, moreover, it returns the line number relative to the range.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^---/,/^## \[Unreleased\]/c\something else' file
```

Change the lines between two regexp to the required string.

Comment: Nicely done. To make it work with BSD `sed`, an explicit newline is needed after `c\ `; using an `$'…'` string in `bash`: `sed -e $'/^---/,/^## \\[Unreleased\\]/c\\\nsomething else' file`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v RS="\0" 'gsub(/---\n\n## \[Unreleased\]\n/,"something")+1' file
```

give this line a try.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This example may help you.

```
$ cat f
Some text
---

## [Unreleased]
More text here

$ seq 1 5  >mydata.txt

$ cat mydata.txt 
1
2
3
4
5

$ awk '/^---/{f=1; while(getline < c)print;close(c);next}/^## \[Unreleased\]/{f=0;next}!f' c="mydata.txt"  f
Some text
1
2
3
4
5
More text here
```

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` solution that:

- is portable (POSIX-compliant).
- can deal with any number of lines between the start line and the end line of the block, and potentially with multiple blocks (although they'd all be replaced with the same text).
- reads the file line by line (as opposed to reading the entire file at once).

```
awk -v new='something else' '
 /^---$/ { f=1; next }                               # Block start: set flag, skip line
 f && /^## \[Unreleased\]$/ { f=0; print new; next } # Block end: unset flag, print new txt 
 ! f                                                 # Print line, if before or after block
' file
```